# How to have only one marker in google map?

Tags: ajax, dictionary

I have made a google map with ajax but the problem is that for each word that I type it makes a marker how to change this in order that when the user has finished to type the address it shows the marker?
http://jsbin.com/qupociri/2/edit

Comment: this is the link http://jsbin.com/qupociri/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

You have a Markers array but were not adding the marker you created into it so they we're just being sat into the map with no handle to them, i linked them up and added a loop that will go though the markers remove them from the map and then remove them from the markers array please see below.

http://jsbin.com/qupociri/5/edit

Removed array support for there is now only one maker see if that does it for you.

Try this one
http://jsbin.com/qupociri/6/edit

I have now added a timeout on the input so that if your still typing the address it wont run the function this way it can possibly lose a copy of the variable that holds the marker so it should always erase the the marker from last time it ran. if this does not work try it in another browser as i dont seem to have any problems in my google chrome with it.

Comment: Thanks a a lot But I don't know why sometimes your link works perfect and sometimes there are more than one marker on the page

Comment: strange i can't replicate the problem how's it happening for you / what are you typing in?

Comment: Edited the post to change from array to single marker

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately it does not work it still makes more than one marker

Comment: Thanks a lot But it doesn't work I have a found the solution I put the links later